# What is the end result of Batch Job?

Tags: mule

[image: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/_images/batch_phases.png]

In the image below,what will be the result at the end of ON COMPLETE block?
Here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/batch-processing, it is mentioned that gives both options, a BatchResultObject and also records of successful and unsuccessful logs. But i need to know that what should be the default result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the On Complete phase, Mule will always return a instance of BatchJobResult with JUST the statistics, not the records themselves. the following fields:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/batch-processing-reference#batchjobresult-processing-statistics

If you log it it will look something like this:

```
BatchJobInstanceId:09b38430-8474-11e4-9c5c-0a0027000000
          Number of TotalRecords: 0
          ProcessedRecords: 0
          Number of sucessfull Records: 0
          Number of failed Records: 0
          ElapsedTime in milliseconds: 0
```